# I want to remove 3 LED's from a small circuit board. Need a bit of help

Tags: led, usb

I have a 4 port USB hub with 3 INCREDIBLY BRIGHT led lights on the circuit board I would prefer removed.

I've googled a bit and found a user of this site actually describe the process very well.. [Here](http://reviews.bestbuy.com/answers/3545/product/9775443/rocketfish-4-port-usb-2-0-hub-questions-answers/questions.htm)

My knowledge of working with this stuff is next to none, and I do not have a soldering iron.

But, this user suggests soldering off or 'cut off with a knife', a TINY resistor next to each LED. I've poked at it a bit and it doesn't seem to want to budge. I'm worried I will break something or scratch it if I try much harder..

So my main question is, I believe I could much easier pull the led's off with pliers. Would this work as well? Is this dangerous? Or any tips on getting the resistors off without a soldering iron?

Here is a photo of the top with the resistors in question. Click for a high-res version.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ57b.jpg?4098]

And here is a photo of the bottom with the LED's I'd like to yank out.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrM8s.jpg?4933]

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ha!  I uploaded that description.  Good to know someone else read it.

Comment: Yes haha, I noticed you linked to imgur, so I searched for your name on reddit, then googled your name. Apologies for stalking but I found this site which may help quite a bit. These lights are ridiculous!

Comment: @user2785 - No problem.  I have a unique username because some other "Kevin Vermeer"s seem to have taken all the other reasonable permutations of my name: kevin.vermeer, kvermeer, vermeerk, kevinv, etc.

Comment: ..and I was just thinking about changing my username to something more professional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey!  That reminds me, I need to desolder those LEDs and make some throwies.  Those things lighted the room with the fury of a thousand suns.

Anyways, the goal of the process is to somehow disconnect the trace which goes from the tiny resistors toward the center of the board, and the side of the LED which connects to the ground plane.

You can do this by (1) removing the resistor or LEDs with a soldering iron, or (2) by removing the resistor with another tool (pocketknife), (3) by cutting the trace itself, or by (4) cutting the LEDs with flush cutters/dikes, or, as you suggested, (5) by pulling with a pair of pliers.

1. Removal with a soldering iron is the least destructive and most professional way of doing it.  It's easy, just put your tip next to it, wait for the solder to become shiny, and push it off.
2. OK, you can break the resistor off of the pads.  I got my new USB hub, came home, and started dd'ing two drives to a third (which was why I needed the hub). Then, I turned off the lights (the ones on my ceiling) and tried to go to bed.  I probably acted rashly by not covering them temporarily and waiting until the next day to use a soldering iron, but as long as you don't create any connections that weren't there before, your goal is to break this connection, you can't really do any damage.
3. The trace is probably 1oz copper, which is about 1/4th the thickness of aluminum foil.  It's glued to the sturdy FR4 board, and it's underneath a layer of soldermask, but it's easy enough to cut.  A few scores back and forth should do it.
4. The LEDs are extremely bright, and in an unusual package/pin spacing.  They're probably worth $0.25 plus shipping, and would be hard to replace.  The resistors, on the other hand, are $0.02, and are easy to get. I opted not to cut them off, but if you can disconnect the two pins, you'll succeed in breaking the circuit.
5. The LEDs do have 22ga pins, and are firmly soldered to the PCB.  This is a metal to metal bond; you won't just pull the LED out of the hole.  You will mangle it.  If you mangle it enough, you will likely succeed.  However, cutting something is probably a little easier.

And yes, I did get to bed, the LEDs ceased to blind me, and the USB hub is still working great.

Comment: YES!!! I DID IT. Thanks a ton man. I actually used your original pocketknife method (number 2), but your posts here helped clairfy a bit. I was unsure what to do from the original post. So happy. I was picking at all differnt angles, but when that first resister popped off and I figured it out, it was like winning the olympics.  YES. YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.    I wish you all the best of luck with future tinkering and thank everyone for their comments.

Comment: An epic tale of desperate, on the spot hacking if I ever heard one.

Answer (score 6):

When I'm confronting an INCREDIBLY BRIGHT LED and I don't care about the power consumption, I simply cover it with a small piece of electrical tape or liquid electrical tape. It would also be quite easy to push the resistors off using the tip of a hot soldering iron.

Don't yank them off. Snip the leads with a flat cutter.

Comment: I agree, just cover them over

Comment: No, Joe, you don't understand. These things are INCREDIBLY BRIGHT.  They're also in a tight spot in a translucent case, so you'd likely overheat something if you put electrical tape or glue on them.

Comment: They definitely won't overheat if covered, and if the LED breaks because it has overheated -- problem solved! The tape might not fit in the case however.

Comment: I'm glad you said NOT to do the tape thing, I was unsure.. Last night I used electrical tape on them.. I knew it wasn't the best idea.. And, there was still enough light leak to cast a big blue glow in my room. They are just very hard to cover thoroughly.  SO you're saying this is not the type of LED I can just yank off with pliers?

Comment: How many people have this silly hub?

Comment: @user2785 - The solder blob on the back of the PCB will never pull through the hole.  It's fairly thick wire, a metal-to-metal bond, and a copper-clad hole in a fiberglass board.  Cutting them will be much easier.

Comment: @Joe - It was the cheapest one in stock at my local Best Buy.  I presume this means a LOT of people.

Comment: ...or paint the LEDs with black paint.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to hide them, just use a marker pen to cover them up, or some opaque glue

Answer (score 1):

Just a touch of nail polish, preferably red, will completely cover the LEDs and since they don't produce heat there is no risk of overheating.